# Add html to custom page in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to have a simple blank page on my wordpress-created website where I can add my custom html code and some js code.
I got so far to make a page template that I can choose and the page is actually blank.

So far so good: now, when I add my html code into it, there is nothing. Also, when I inspect the page, there really is no html code whatsoever on this custom page.

Where is my mistake?

Code for the template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Raw Page
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a template

In your theme folder create a template file my-template.php

Include

```
<?php /* Template Name : My Template */ ?>
```

at the top of the page

To then display the content from the Wordpress page, in your template file include the call to display the content...

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    the_content();
endwhile; ?>
```

Go into wordpress, create a blank page, select the template "My Template" on right hand side and save it.

Comment: That's what I've done, but if I want to add html to this blank page, there is nothing on it when I choose my new template.

Comment: Sure, sorry. See above.

Comment: just to be clear, where exactly are you posting the html code? on the template file or on the wordpress page?

Comment: because if its on the wordpress page, you must call the function to show that content in the template file

Comment: Oh that's probably it. I write it on the wordpress site. How could I 'connect' the html code on the wordpress page to the template? That would be awesome!

Comment: Ive edited the answer, you use the loop https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop to find the posts or pages, then `the_content()` function outputs the data from the WordPress page

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much @Adrian. One more thing one, maybe you know that: the styling in my html is not automatically adopted, right? Any advise on that?

Comment: the styling in all your code throughout template files and wordpress pages can be controlled through style.css in your theme folder